# How to load custom javascript file into asp.net application Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I want to add and load java script file (Spectrum).

I add this file into solution and then add into bundle.config and render the bundle into master page header.

But visual studio show the error that spectrum method does not support.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "spectrum method"?

Comment: Provide some code other useful information so that we can help you. Provide the code what you added in bundle config and bundle